# The service "assetic.helper.static" has a dependency on a non-existent service "assets.packages"

Tags: symfony

I have strange error only id prod mode. 
It shown on page view (in apache errors log) or any terminal operation like here.

```
grek@grek-Inspiron-11-3147:~/PhpstormProjects/mea.crm4/www$ sudo  rm -rf app/cache/*
[sudo] password for grek: 
grek@grek-Inspiron-11-3147:~/PhpstormProjects/mea.crm4/www$ php app/console cache:clear
Clearing the cache for the dev environment with debug true
grek@grek-Inspiron-11-3147:~/PhpstormProjects/mea.crm4/www$ php app/console cache:clear --env=prod



  [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException]                         
  The service "assetic.helper.static" has a dependency on a non-existent service "assets.packages".
```

i server error log i get

```
[Thu Sep 10 16:33:35.726563 2015] [:error] [pid 1552] [client 127.0.0.1:47870] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Exception\\ServiceNotFoundException' with message 'The service "assetic.helper.static" has a dependency on a non-existent service "assets.packages".' in /home/grek/PhpstormProjects/mea.crm4/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php:58\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/grek/PhpstormProjects/mea.crm4/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php(42): Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Compiler\\CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass->processReferences(Array)\n#1 /home/grek/PhpstormProjects/mea.crm4/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php(36): Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Compiler\\CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass->processDefinition(Object(Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Definition))\n#2  in /home/grek/PhpstormProjects/mea.crm4/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/CheckExceptionOnInval
```

here is my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/", "Mea":"vendor/", "mea":"vendor/Mea/CoreBundle/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.6.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3,<2.5",
        "doctrine/dbal": "<2.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.12",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.2",


        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "*",

        "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "~1.1@dev",

        "zetacomponents/mail": "dev-master",
        "html2text/html2text": "dev-master",

        "weotch/phpthumb": "dev-master",
        "hashids/hashids": "0.3.*@dev",
        "egeloen/google-map-bundle": "*",
        "oh/google-map-form-type-bundle": "dev-master",
        "meenie/javascript-packer": "dev-master",
        "natxet/CssMin": "dev-master",
        "apy/datagrid-bundle": "dev-master",
        "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "~1.5",
        "white-october/pagerfanta-bundle": "~1.0",
        "payum/payum-bundle": "0.14.*",
        "payum/paypal-express-checkout-nvp": "*@stable",
        "payum/offline": "0.14.*",
        "egeloen/ckeditor-bundle": "2.2.*@dev",

        "webit/sms-common": "dev-master",
        "webit/smsapi": "dev-master",
        "webit/smsapi-bundle": "dev-master",

        "ddeboer/data-import": "dev-master",
        "endroid/qrcode": "1.*@dev",
        "vich/uploader-bundle": "0.14.*",

        "Mea/CoreBundle": "dev-master",
        "Mea/InvoiceBundle": "dev-master",
        "Mea/PostBoxBundle": "dev-master",
        "Mea/Emailer": "dev-master",
        "Mea/ContactBundle": "dev-master",
        "Mea/TaskBundle": "dev-master",
        "Mea/MailOfficeBundle": "dev-master",
        "Mea/LogBundle": "dev-master",
        "Mea/AccountancyBundle": "dev-master",
        "Mea/MementoBundle": "dev-master",
        "Mea/KeywordsBundle": "dev-master",

        "egeloen/ckeditor-bundle": "2.2.*@dev",
        "knplabs/knp-gaufrette-bundle": "*@dev",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "salavert/time-ago-in-words": "1.*",
        "astina/social-links-bundle":"dev-master",
        "liip/imagine-bundle": "~1.2",
        "symfony/proxy-manager-bridge": "~2.3",
        "fpn/tag-bundle": "0.9.*",
        "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "^1.2"


    },
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:grekpg/meakeywordsbundle.git"
    },

        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:grekpg/meataskbundle.git"
        },

        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:grekpg/meamementobundle.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:grekpg/meacorebundle.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:grekpg/meainvoicebundle.git"
        },

        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:grekpg/postboxbundle.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:grekpg/emailer.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:grekpg/meacontactbundle.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:grekpg/meataskbundle.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:grekpg/meamailofficebundle.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:grekpg/mealogbundle.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:grekpg/meaaccountancybundle.git"
        }
    ],

    "require-dev": {
      "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "SymfonyStandard\\Composer::hookRootPackageInstall"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-assets-install": "symlink",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.6-dev"
        }

    }
}
```

here is remove verndor and composer update log

```
dogmat@ns372228:~/public_html/dcms4$ rm -rf vendor
dogmat@ns372228:~/public_html/dcms4$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information                                         Updating dependencies (including require-dev)           - Installing zetacomponents/base (1.9)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing zetacomponents/mail (dev-master 36ab3b9)
    Cloning 36ab3b991d39f850aa3f3ba433a2a2b68a4325bd

  - Installing html2text/html2text (dev-master 35e78a7)
    Cloning 35e78a729161905703744f907c165d73398b614e

  - Installing weotch/phpthumb (dev-master f5c1d2e)
    Cloning f5c1d2ef2e9de3bded7483778618bf8cac2511c3

  - Installing hashids/hashids (0.3.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing psr/log (1.0.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing twig/twig (v1.21.2)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/lexer (v1.0.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/annotations (v1.2.7)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/collections (v1.3.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/cache (v1.4.2)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/inflector (v1.0.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/common (v2.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/symfony (v2.6.11)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing oh/google-map-form-type-bundle (dev-master 270d3fb)
    Cloning 270d3fbdb5ba456f2c3313a6b3c69d1d3ba7d12b

  - Installing apy/datagrid-bundle (dev-master e961c19)
    Cloning e961c1958cc3d9a90cc89eff8d94a390661b74c5

  - Installing true/punycode (v2.0.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing league/url (3.3.5)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing kriswallsmith/buzz (v0.15)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing payum/core (0.14.5)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing payum/offline (0.14.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing webit/sms-common (dev-master d3134d1)
    Cloning d3134d173629ef8c80e80cc33cdbd34684891b04

  - Installing webit/smsapi (dev-master 50d4f0b)
    Cloning 50d4f0b91cf151e1b0de71f2aafb8a50b59d0675

  - Installing webit/smsapi-bundle (dev-master 34c9ebb)
    Cloning 34c9ebbdc5883173414d71f329af96b5b833dcdb

  - Installing ddeboer/data-import (dev-master e786be6)
    Cloning e786be6eec05fe1c1054c561ee2adfaa6f3a4e71

  - Installing natxet/cssmin (dev-master 4026975)
    Cloning 4026975145f645a77e087a26e7b0a1c9209b0191

  - Installing meenie/javascript-packer (dev-master dcab015)
    Cloning dcab0159ae1ed9d7535c034fb8afe1e4c3495d22

  - Installing mea/corebundle (dev-master eae81f5)
    Cloning eae81f5e6921a9a08ace9c469daedf3659a6f5eb

  - Installing mea/invoicebundle (dev-master 8bee906)
    Cloning 8bee90622bb4ced3d23583501fc1f31b9c87d51f

  - Installing jms/metadata (1.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing vich/uploader-bundle (v0.14.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing mea/postboxbundle (dev-master 0b8bd4f)
    Cloning 0b8bd4f58cb685a149ec904cbca6a9ee433cfde0

  - Installing mea/emailer (dev-master 08baa1b)
    Cloning 08baa1b0da7b1edcb5db99d5a20fb125eda415e3

  - Installing mea/contactbundle (dev-master db7fff2)
    Cloning db7fff238b86cb5fe187d4c36dce3db53262ab09

  - Installing mea/mailofficebundle (dev-master d49ded9)
    Cloning d49ded970040439a549a155dbe44b5c0f1d77bd0

  - Installing mea/logbundle (dev-master 6f4a8a8)
    Cloning 6f4a8a8b67664b193e10c1014e24551f878adda7

  - Installing mea/accountancybundle (dev-master 9e48faf)
    Cloning 9e48fafeb3219398b809c076c897d8c71d32395b

  - Installing mea/mementobundle (dev-master dc75d8a)
    Cloning dc75d8a83370baea367c50cdb5de3a96fc2d875e

  - Installing mea/keywordsbundle (dev-master 09e5d9d)
    Cloning 09e5d9d738e5fd2a506275decb8f0553088720ca

  - Installing sensio/framework-extra-bundle (v3.0.10)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing social-links/social-links (v1.3.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing astina/social-links-bundle (dev-master b878b7c)
    Cloning b878b7c0a1b0ff2915b1a953351055099444856a

  - Installing doctrine/dbal (v2.4.4)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/orm (v2.4.8)
    Loading from cache

    Skipped installation of bin bin/doctrine for package doctrine/orm: name conflicts with an existing file
    Skipped installation of bin bin/doctrine.php for package doctrine/orm: name conflicts with an existing file
  - Installing fpn/doctrine-extensions-taggable (v0.9.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing fpn/tag-bundle (v0.9.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle (v1.0.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing jdorn/sql-formatter (v1.2.17)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing doctrine/doctrine-bundle (v1.5.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing twig/extensions (v1.3.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing kriswallsmith/assetic (v1.3.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/assetic-bundle (v2.7.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v5.4.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/swiftmailer-bundle (v2.3.8)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing monolog/monolog (1.17.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/monolog-bundle (v2.7.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing sensiolabs/security-checker (v3.0.1)
    Loading from cache

    Skipped installation of bin security-checker for package sensiolabs/security-checker: name conflicts with an existing file
  - Installing sensio/distribution-bundle (v3.0.31)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing friendsofsymfony/user-bundle (v1.3.6)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing behat/transliterator (v1.0.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing gedmo/doctrine-extensions (v2.4.6)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle (dev-master 7b31445)
    Cloning 7b3144572617b0555f9a443317dbc2f9cf5b524e

  - Installing egeloen/json-builder (1.0.3)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing egeloen/google-map (1.4.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing egeloen/google-map-bundle (2.2.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing willdurand/jsonp-callback-validator (v1.1.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle (1.5.4)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing pagerfanta/pagerfanta (v1.0.3)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing white-october/pagerfanta-bundle (v1.0.3)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing payum/payum-bundle (0.14.4)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing payum/paypal-express-checkout-nvp (0.14.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing egeloen/ckeditor-bundle (2.2.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing endroid/qrcode (dev-master 6bfcfa4)
    Cloning 6bfcfa458c1ea1de1f83b93619b28ef238857689

  - Installing mea/taskbundle (dev-master c12f944)
    Cloning c12f9445ca55323a0235fa1c74c3cffd677a3542

  - Installing knplabs/gaufrette (v0.1.9)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing knplabs/knp-gaufrette-bundle (dev-master b6dbd93)
    Cloning b6dbd93d1263f3f57d9c0b5e3b5935b281fcbd9c

  - Installing incenteev/composer-parameter-handler (v2.1.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing salavert/time-ago-in-words (v1.6.2)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing imagine/imagine (0.6.2)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing liip/imagine-bundle (1.3.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing knplabs/knp-snappy (0.4.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle (v1.3)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing sensio/generator-bundle (v2.5.3)
    Loading from cache

apy/datagrid-bundle suggests installing ext-intl (Translate the grid)
apy/datagrid-bundle suggests installing PHPExcel (Export the grid (Excel, HTML or PDF))
payum/core suggests installing payum/paypal-pro-checkout-nvp (If you want to use paypal pro checkout)
payum/core suggests installing payum/paypal-rest (If you want to use paypal rest gateway)
payum/core suggests installing payum/paypal-ipn (If you want to use paypal instant payment notifications(Paypal IPN))
payum/core suggests installing payum/authorize-net-aim (If you want to use Authorize.Net AIM payment gateway)
payum/core suggests installing payum/be2bill (If you want to use be2bill payment gateway)
payum/core suggests installing payum/payex (If you want to use payex payment gateway)
payum/core suggests installing payum/omnipay-bridge (If you want to use omnipay's gateways)
payum/core suggests installing doctrine/mongodb-odm (If you want to store models to mongo doctrin2 ODM)
payum/core suggests installing zendframework/zend-db (If you want to store models to Zend Db ORM)
payum/core suggests installing propel/propel1 (If you want to store models to Propel1 ORM)
payum/core suggests installing propel/propel (If you want to store models to Propel2 ORM)
ddeboer/data-import suggests installing phpoffice/phpexcel (If you want to use the ExcelReader)
vich/uploader-bundle suggests installing doctrine/phpcr-odm (~1.0)
vich/uploader-bundle suggests installing doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle (*)
vich/uploader-bundle suggests installing willdurand/propel-eventdispatcher-bundle (>=1.2)
sensio/framework-extra-bundle suggests installing symfony/psr-http-message-bridge (To use the PSR-7 converters)
kriswallsmith/assetic suggests installing leafo/lessphp (Assetic provides the integration with the lessphp LESS compiler)
kriswallsmith/assetic suggests installing leafo/scssphp (Assetic provides the integration with the scssphp SCSS compiler)
kriswallsmith/assetic suggests installing ptachoire/cssembed (Assetic provides the integration with phpcssembed to embed data uris)
kriswallsmith/assetic suggests installing leafo/scssphp-compass (Assetic provides the integration with the SCSS compass plugin)
kriswallsmith/assetic suggests installing patchwork/jsqueeze (Assetic provides the integration with the JSqueeze JavaScript compressor)
symfony/assetic-bundle suggests installing kriswallsmith/spork (to be able to dump assets in parallel)
monolog/monolog suggests installing graylog2/gelf-php (Allow sending log messages to a GrayLog2 server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing raven/raven (Allow sending log messages to a Sentry server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing doctrine/couchdb (Allow sending log messages to a CouchDB server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing ruflin/elastica (Allow sending log messages to an Elastic Search server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing videlalvaro/php-amqplib (Allow sending log messages to an AMQP server using php-amqplib)
monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-amqp (Allow sending log messages to an AMQP server (1.0+ required))
monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-mongo (Allow sending log messages to a MongoDB server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing aws/aws-sdk-php (Allow sending log messages to AWS services like DynamoDB)
monolog/monolog suggests installing rollbar/rollbar (Allow sending log messages to Rollbar)
monolog/monolog suggests installing php-console/php-console (Allow sending log messages to Google Chrome)
friendsofsymfony/user-bundle suggests installing willdurand/propel-typehintable-behavior (Needed when using the propel implementation)
gedmo/doctrine-extensions suggests installing doctrine/mongodb-odm (to use the extensions with the MongoDB ODM)
stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle suggests installing doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle (to use the MongoDB ODM extensions)
egeloen/google-map suggests installing widop/http-adapter (Allows to use services)
egeloen/google-map suggests installing willdurand/geocoder (Allows to use geocoding service)
pagerfanta/pagerfanta suggests installing mandango/mandango (To use the MandangoAdapter.)
pagerfanta/pagerfanta suggests installing doctrine/mongodb-odm (To use the DoctrineODMMongoDBAdapter.)
pagerfanta/pagerfanta suggests installing doctrine/phpcr-odm (To use the DoctrineODMPhpcrAdapter. >= 1.1.0)
pagerfanta/pagerfanta suggests installing propel/propel1 (To use the PropelAdapter)
pagerfanta/pagerfanta suggests installing solarium/solarium (To use the SolariumAdapter.)
payum/payum-bundle suggests installing sonata-project/admin-bundle (If you want to configure payments in the backend.)
egeloen/ckeditor-bundle suggests installing helios-ag/fm-elfinder-bundle (Allows to use the elfinder as CKEditor file manager)
knplabs/gaufrette suggests installing dropbox-php/dropbox-php (to use the Dropbox adapter)
knplabs/gaufrette suggests installing rackspace/php-opencloud (to use Opencloud adapter)
knplabs/gaufrette suggests installing google/apiclient (to use GoogleCloudStorage adapter)
knplabs/gaufrette suggests installing herzult/php-ssh (to use SFtp adapter)
knplabs/gaufrette suggests installing phpseclib/phpseclib (to use PhpseclibSftp adapter)
knplabs/gaufrette suggests installing aws/aws-sdk-php (to use the Amazon S3 adapter)
knplabs/gaufrette suggests installing amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-php (to use the legacy Amazon S3 adapters)
knplabs/gaufrette suggests installing microsoft/windowsazure (to use Microsoft Azure Blob Storage adapter)
knplabs/gaufrette suggests installing ext-mongo (*)
imagine/imagine suggests installing ext-imagick (to use the Imagick implementation)
imagine/imagine suggests installing ext-gmagick (to use the Gmagick implementation)
liip/imagine-bundle suggests installing aws/aws-sdk-php (Add it if you'd like to use aws v2 or v3 resolver)
liip/imagine-bundle suggests installing amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-php (Add it if you'd like to use aws v1 resolver)
knplabs/knp-snappy suggests installing h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64 (Provides wkhtmltopdf-amd64 binary for Linux-compatible machines, use version `~0.12` as dependency)
knplabs/knp-snappy suggests installing h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-i386 (Provides wkhtmltopdf-i386 binary for Linux-compatible machines, use version `~0.12` as dependency)
knplabs/knp-snappy suggests installing wemersonjanuario/wkhtmltopdf-windows (Provides wkhtmltopdf executable for Windows, use version `~0.12` as dependency)
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
> Incenteev\ParameterHandler\ScriptHandler::buildParameters
Updating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache
Clearing the cache for the dev environment with debug true
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::installAssets
Trying to install assets as symbolic links.
Installing assets for Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle into web/bundles/framework
The assets were installed using symbolic links.
Installing assets for Ivory\CKEditorBundle into web/bundles/ivoryckeditor
The assets were installed using symbolic links.
Installing assets for Oh\GoogleMapFormTypeBundle into web/bundles/ohgooglemapformtype
The assets were installed using symbolic links.
Installing assets for FOS\JsRoutingBundle into web/bundles/fosjsrouting
The assets were installed using symbolic links.
Installing assets for AppBundle into web/bundles/app
The assets were installed using symbolic links.
Installing assets for Mea\KeywordsBundle into web/bundles/meakeywords
The assets were installed using symbolic links.
Installing assets for Mea\CoreBundle into web/bundles/meacore
The assets were installed using symbolic links.
Installing assets for Mea\PostBoxBundle into web/bundles/meapostbox
The assets were installed using symbolic links.
Installing assets for Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle into web/bundles/sensiodistribution
The assets were installed using symbolic links.
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget
dogmat@ns372228:~/public_html/dcms4$ php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql --env=prod



  [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException]                         
  The service "assetic.helper.static" has a dependency on a non-existent service "assets.packages".
```

Comment: Do you use any `assetic` service?

Comment: Can you paste your `composer.json` file? Try to delete the `vendor/` directory then run `composer update`.

Comment: I paste composer.json and log from delete vendor / update

Comment: @KévinDunglas' method worked for me, delete vendor and do composer install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was in FPNTagBundle, i remove it and error gone...

Comment: I got the same error, i removed all vendors and reinstalled them but not works...

Answer (score 6):

Ok to solve this bad bad bad problem that is killing my app just in prod evironnement without any way to solve it, just i put in config.yml this:

```
services:
    assets.packages:
        synthetic: true
```

and by magic, it works...

I'm really tired to try to solve things that SHOULD works out of the box...